# How to remove opkg from a Yocto image

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Using Poky (v. 13.0 - Yocto 1.8), I am trying to build the `core-image-minimal` but excluding the `opkg` package.

In the generated rootfs, I still have a `/usr/lib/opkg/` populated folder.

I tried to play with the following in my build/conf/local.conf

```
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove += " package-management"
IMAGE_FEATURES_remove += " package-management"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES_remove += " package-management opkg"
IMAGE_INSTALL_remove += " package-management opkg"

POKY_DEFAULT_EXTRA_RRECOMMENDS = ""
```

I saw that in `meta-yocto/conf/distro/poky-tiny.conf` there is the following, which I tried to add (still in my `local.conf` without success)

```
PACKAGECONFIG_pn-opkg-utils = ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if you ensure that `IMAGE_FEATURES` doesn't contain `package-management`, that should be enough. (Unless you manually install eg `opkg`).

Have you looked at `/usr/lib/opkg`? In my image, that directory only contains `alternatives`, which in turns holds information about alternative versions of installed applications. See eg `update-alternatives`.

Do you have any other files or directories under `/usr/lib/opkg`?

============== Update ==============
These files are not really needed, unless you want/need to run `update-alternatives`. This could also be run if you do package based updates. However, on a read-only rootfs, these shouldn't be needed.

Something like this could be used if you want `/usr/lib/opkg` to be removed:

```
remove_alternative_files () {
    rm -rf ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/usr/lib/opkg
}

ROOTFS_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND += "remove_alternative_files;"
```

This can be added either directly in your recipe, or if you have a custom image-class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Indeed, I only have an `alternatives` folder in `/usr/lib/opkg`. Any pointer to remove this folder and its content or is it really needed ?